# Struggling with a simple JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I feel like I'm overcomplicating the problem. I have a situation where I have 2 tables:

```
orders:
- order_id

order_products:
- order_id
- status
```

If each order product can have an independent status (e.g.: shipped, backordered, etc.) I want to be able to write a query to say "show me all orders whose products have all been shipped."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, because it is more than a "simple join".  There are several ways to approach this.  One method uses aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select op.order_id
from order_products op
group by op.order_id
having sum(case when op.status = 'shipped' then 1 else 0 end) = count(*);
```

That is, count the number of rows with a status of shipped, and be sure that it is all of them for a given row.  If you want more information about the order, just join that table in as well.

Another method uses `join` and looks like this:

```
select op.*
from orders o join
     order_products op
     on o.order_id = op.orderId and op.status <> 'shipped';
```

This will return all instances of products that don't have a status of shipped.  If you just want the order information, you can use `select distinct o.*` instead of `select op.*`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to look for all orders where NOT EXISTS any item in a status other than shipped.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM orders o 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1 
           FROM order_products p 
          WHERE o.order_id=p.order_id 
            AND status <> 'shipped'
       )
```

In SQL Server this sort of NOT EXISTS query is often more efficient than then using a join. I'm not sure with postgresql.

This of course assumes that shipped is the terminal status. Otherwise we;d need to account for an ordering of status, etc. It also assume that all orders have items, as order without item in any status would also meet the criteria. The latter seems like a very safe assumption.